# Calling User Defined Function in Linq to SQL partial entity class

Tags: .net, sql-server, t-sql, linq-to-sql

I have a user defined function sitting on my SQL server. I want to utilise this within one of the partial entity classes created by the Linq to SQL designer.

I know it's very simple to do when you have access to the datacontext, however in the partial entity classes I obviously don't.

Does anyone know of a way either to access the datacontext that owns a particular entity OR call a udf directly from that entity?

Thanks

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/08/tip-24-how-to-get-the-objectcontext-from-an-entity.aspx - that might work for you, or you could do some sort of static method on the entity context object that returned a context (checking for thread safety).

Comment: It looks to me as if that blog is only for Linq to Entities. I'm using Linq to SQL so need a "DataContext" not a an "EntityContext" unfortunately.

Comment: It's the same basic concept - navigating 'up' to the context from the object won't work for you out of the box.  You need either to put a reference to the context in thread local storage per the blog, add a method to your partial class that gives it the context, or you can have a static method that gives you a context - basically either cache the context (entity or data) in the thread, explicitly make a reference in your partial entities, or make it available to everyone.  No great options unfortunately.